# Mesh not following bone after parenting and painting

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

The mesh is not moving at all even after i parented and painted the weights on that bone's vertex group. I tried it on all the bones but I have the same problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way of solving this is to select the object then the armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select Armature Deform. If you did that you should also be able to select a Vertex Group by selecting the Bone while in Weight Painting mode.

Answer (score 2):

When you parent an armature to a mesh you need to go into the mesh's object properties and make sure that under Relations->Parent you have the proper Armature object selected and make sure the type is set to armature not Object or Bone.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out. I had parented it with empty weights then used the Data Transfer modifier, but parent's type was set to Object.

Comment: Jesus thank you so much. I've been working in as a rigging technician for almost a year and never encountered this problem. It was driving me MAD. I didn't knew Blender gave relations a "Parent Type". Thanks a lot !

Comment: -Edit : nevermind : I was just assigning weights to a bone with the "Deform" option deactivated...